# how to do urlopen over ipv4 by default

Tags: python, ipv6, urllib, ipv4

What is the way to do urlopen in python such that even if the underlying machine has ipv6 networking enabled, the request is sent via ipv4 instead of ipv6?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Force python mechanize/urllib2 to only use A requests?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2014534/force-python-mechanize-urllib2-to-only-use-a-requests)

Comment: or maybe [how to force python httplib library to use only A requests](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1540749/how-to-force-python-httplib-library-to-use-only-a-requests)?

Comment: `urllib.urlopen()` or `urllib2.urlopen()`?

Comment: Update / Solution: I tried the suggestion as logged here stackoverflow.com/a/6319043/420284 and it does work for me.., even though it is ugly hack but probably the simplest for me.

Answer (score 1):

I had a look into the source code. Unfortunately, `urllib.urlopen()` seems to use `httplib.HTTP()`, which doesn't even allow setting a source address.

`urllib2.urlopen()` uses `httplib.HTTPConnection()` which you could inherit from and create a class which by default sets a source address `'0.0.0.0'` instead of `''`. Then you could somehow inject that new overridden class into the `urllib2` stuff by creating a "new" `HTTPHandler()` (look how it's done in `urllib2.py`) and a new opener which you `build_opener()` and/or `install_opener()`.

Sorry for not being very exact, but I never have done such a thing and don't know exactly how that works.

Comment: I tried the suggestion as logged here http://stackoverflow.com/a/6319043/420284 and it does work for me.., even though it is ugly hack but probably the simplest for me.