# Does shared library (.so) need to change if my IOS app support IPV6

Tags: ios, ios9, ipv6, ipv4

Apple announced that IOS 9 will support IPV6-only network services. All apps submitted to the App store must support IPV6.

Now, My app uses a shared library(.so), the library uses IPV4-specific Apis. so I don't know whether the library needs to change.

Can anyone answer my question?

Comment: Did you even tried if it works ?

Comment: I just test it in IPV4 network and it works fine.

Answer (score 1):

If your app uses IPv4-specific APIs or hard-coded IP addresses, you will need to make some changes. Learn how to ensure compatibility by reading  [Supporting IPv6 DNS64/NAT64 Networks](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/NetworkingInternetWeb/Conceptual/NetworkingOverview/UnderstandingandPreparingfortheIPv6Transition/UnderstandingandPreparingfortheIPv6Transition.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010220-CH213-SW1) and watch Your App and [Next Generation Networks](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2015/719/).You can check some other detail [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11228706/6339505)

Comment: I just want to know whether the shared library needs to change.

Answer (score 0):

It simple to answer.

1) Test your library over ipv6. 
2.1) It's ok so you don't have any change to do
2.2) It fails, you need to investigate and do some changes.

Comment: Thx. The testing fails over IPv6 and now the server only support IPV4. I'd like to get the officer answer whether to do some changes.